# Is it possible to apply validation constraints to a Symfony login form?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Is it possible to apply validation constraints to a Symfony login form?

To me it looks like that won't work. I use Symfony 5.2

I have created a Symfony login form as described on the documentation page "https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html".

Now I would like to validate the form and have created the following constraints for this in "validation.yaml".

```
App \ Entity \ User:
  properties:
    username:
      - NotBlank:
          message: 'form.user.username.not_blank'
    password:
      - NotBlank:
          message: 'form.user.password.not_blank'
```

Unfortunately the constraints are ignored.

If I leave the username and password fields blank, I get a message that the login failed. In such a case, I would like to receive the constraint message that the username and password cannot be empty.

I didn't get any further during my research on the Internet.

Could it be that no validation constraints can be used in a Symfony login form?

Has anyone of you successfully set up validation constraints in a Symfony 5 login form and can you give me a tip on what to look out for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon a similar issue - and used the following solution:

Since the authentification happens before the regular form validation I implemented a custom validation in the 'authenticate' method of my LoginFormAuthenticator:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request): PassportInterface
{
    $credentials = $request->get('login');

    <snip>

    $errors = $this->validateCredentials($credentials);
    if (0 !== $errors->count()) {

        throw new AuthenticationException();
    }

    return new Passport(
        new UserBadge($credentials['email']),
        new PasswordCredentials($credentials['password']),
        [
            new CsrfTokenBadge('login_token', $credentials['_csrf_token']),
            new RememberMeBadge(),
        ]
    );
}
```

The validateCredentials method which stores the $error-object in the session:

```
    public function validateCredentials($credentials) {

    $constraints = new Assert\Collection([
        'fields' => [
            'email' =>
                new Assert\Sequentially([
                    new Assert\NotBlank([
                        'message' => 'login.email.not_blank'
                    ]),
                    new Assert\Email([
                        'message' => 'login.email'
                    ])
                ]),

            <snip>

        ],
        'allowExtraFields' => true
    ]);
    $errors = $this->validator->validate(
        $credentials,
        $constraints
    );

    if (0 !== $errors->count()) {
        $this->session->set('login-errors', $errors);
    } else {
        $this->session->remove('login-errors');
    }

    return $errors;
}
```

The SecurityController fetches the $error-object from the session and adds the respective errors to the login form:

```
    $loginForm = $this->createForm(LoginType::class, $formData);
    $loginErrors = $request->getSession()->get('login-errors');

    if ($loginErrors) {
        foreach ($loginErrors as $error) {
            $propertyPath = trim($error->getPropertyPath(), '[]');
            $errorMessage = $error->getMessage();
            $loginForm->get($propertyPath)->addError(new FormError($errorMessage));
        }
    }
```

Most likely not the best approach - but it does the job reasonably well and it's only the login form that makes this extra validation step necessary.

Answer (score 0):

**With model**
You have to add these constraints to the entitiy (if you are using it).
I'd suggest to use the annotations:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#configuration
Just add those to your entity.
In Your Model (Entity):

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class MyClass
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $myVarToBeAsserted;
}
```

**Without model**
If you are using a data class (no model behind the form), you can use annotations as well. But in this case you have to add those to your form itself:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/without_class.html

MyFormType:

```
        $builder->add(
        'birth',
        DateType::class,
        [
            'required' => true,
            'constraints' =>
                [
                    new NotBlank(),
                    new Date()
                ],
            'label' => $labelBirth,
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'html5' => true,
            'attr' =>
                [
                ],
        ]
    );
```

... and in controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm(
        MyFormType::class,
        [
            'data_class' => true
        ],
);
```

What you did btw: You defined the message for those possible assertions. Which would be shown if your assertion NotBlank() would be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your proposed solution.

Your suggestion helped me a lot.

I have now implemented the validation in my login form in this way.

In my LoginFormAuthenticator class I added a new method "validate". This method validates the login form and saves the errors in the session.

```
private function validate(array $credentials)
{
    $user = new User();

    $user->setUsername($credentials['username'])
        ->setPassword($credentials['password']);

    $errors = $this->validator->validate($user);

    if (0 !== $errors->count()) {
        $this->session->set(SessionKey::LOGIN_VALIDATION_ERRORS, $errors);
    } else {
        $this->session->remove(SessionKey::LOGIN_VALIDATION_ERRORS);
    }
}
```

In my SecurityController class, I check whether validation errors are stored in the session. If there are any, I will add them to the login form as you have already described in your post.

```
$loginErrors = $request->getSession()->get(SessionKey::LOGIN_VALIDATION_ERRORS);
if ($loginErrors) {
    foreach ($loginErrors as $error) {
        $propertyPath = trim($error->getPropertyPath(), '[]');
        $errorMessage = $error->getMessage();
        $form->get($propertyPath)->addError(new FormError($errorMessage));
    }
}
```

For me this is a workable solution. Maybe not nice but it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did Symfony 4.4 login form server-side validation. It must be done before Symfony performs its built-in authentication checks: in my AppCustomAuthenticator I added a local validator in the getCredentials() method:

```
public function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = [
        'username' => $request->request->get('username'),
        'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
        'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
    ];

    // I need to validate the login form fields before the actual authentication
    // do NOT validate with entity annotations, but with local validator (otherwise, the User entity validations would trigger errors like it would for create/update User)
    $dataConstraints = new Assert\Collection([            
        'fields' => [
            'username' => [
                new Assert\NotBlank([
                    'message' => 'Username cannot be empty'
                ]),
                new Assert\Length([
                    'min' => 4,
                    'max' => 100,
                    'minMessage' => 'Username is too short. It should have 4 characters or more.',
                    'maxMessage' => 'Username is too long. It should have 100 characters or less.'
                ])
            ],
            'password' => [
                new Assert\NotBlank([
                    'message' => 'Password cannot be empty'
                ]),
                new Assert\Length([
                    'min' => 4,
                    'max' => 100,
                    'minMessage' => 'Password is too short. It should have 4 characters or more.',
                    'maxMessage' => 'Password is too long. It should have 100 characters or less.'
                ])
            ]
        ],
        // to allow more fields in the first parameter of $this->validator->validate() [which is the array of fields to validate], but which have no constraint in the second parameter (in $dataConstraints)
        'allowExtraFields' => true
    ]);

    $errors = $this->validator->validate(
        $credentials,
        $dataConstraints
    );

    if (0 !== $errors->count()) {
        $arrErrors = [];
        foreach($errors as $error){
            $arrErrors[] = $error->getMessage();
        }
        throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Login failed.',$arrErrors);
    } 


    $request->getSession()->set(
        Security::LAST_USERNAME,
        $credentials['username']
    );

    return $credentials;
}
```

So, do not use User entity validator for the login form, because entity Assert constraints are for create/update forms (register user/edit user). Then, in my controller, login route:

```
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="app_login")
 */
public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils)
{
    // if already loggedin, redirect to another page
    // if ($this->getUser()) {
    //     return $this->redirectToRoute('target_path');
    // }

    // here we prepare the errors for the view, if any
    // I made it two-dimensional array, you can do whatever
    $retError = [];

    // get the login error(s)
    $errors = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    // prepare the Login form errors (including the Symfony authentication error; $errors includes any of them, from the exceptions in AppCustomAuthenticator), if any
    if($errors){
        $retError[] = [
            'error_group' => $errors->getMessageKey(),
            'error_items' => $errors->getMessageData()
        ];   
    }  

    return $this->render('site/login.html.php', [
        'last_username' => $lastUsername, 
        'retError' => $retError
    ]);

}
```

In my login.html.php view (PHP templating):

```
<?php if ($retError) { ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                <?php foreach($retError as $error){ ?>
                    <li>
                        <?=$error['error_group'];?>
                        <?php 
                            if(is_array($error['error_items']) && count($error['error_items']) > 0){
                        ?>
                            <ul>
                                <?php foreach($error['error_items'] as $error_item){ ?>
                                    <li><?=$error_item;?></li>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </ul>                            
                        <?php } ?>
                    </li>
                <?php } ?>  
            </ul> 
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```